# How to automatically parsing date time in CSV with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

My csv file has a column with date times in it that look like this :

"2021-01-24 20:10:58"

and I've written the following :

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\foo\data.csv', index_col=1, parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True)    
print(data.dtypes)
```

which shows basically all of my columns as 'object' type.  Can someone help me understand what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a list of column names or indices, e.g. `parse_dates=["col1", "col2"]` or `parse_dates=[1, 2]`. If you pass `parse_dates=True`, only the index column will be parsed.

Per the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

> The behavior is as follows:
>
> boolean. If True -> try parsing the index.
>
> list of int or names. e.g. If [1, 2, 3] -> try parsing columns 1, 2, 3 each as a separate date column.
>
> list of lists. e.g. If [[1, 3]] -> combine columns 1 and 3 and parse as a single date column.
>
> dict, e.g. {‘foo’ : [1, 3]} -> parse columns 1, 3 as date and call result ‘foo’

Comment: OK this seems to solve the issue only when I remove index_col=1.  Any idea why that would be?  Thank you and apologies for not reading the documentation ahead of time.

Comment: Infact calling setIndex does the same thing .  I wonder if setting a column as an index removes it from the dtypes?

Comment: @AmirAfghani bcz it act as the index of the dataframe so when you write df.dtypes the dtypes attribute returns a Series with the data type of each column so dtypes won't work on indexes

Comment: Correct, setting a column as an index removes it from `df.dtypes`. Indices are treated differently than columns. You can access the dtype of the index with `df.index.dtype`.